# Who played the solos at the climax of Bill and Ted Face The Music?

Tags: history

I'm sure this information isn't hard to find if I searched for the right terms, but I have searched and come up with results for how they would have loved to have included Van Halen and about the composer Mark Isham.

I'm just wondering who the person is who played the climactic guitar solos though.

Comment: The [soundtrack credits](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1086064/soundtrack/?ref_=tt_trv_snd) can be found on IMDB.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy questions like this are no longer on topic on music fans.

Comment: @Dom I understand if this doesn't fit under "history" as I hoped it might. But this isn't about transcribing nor finding a particular song as the private feedback I see says for why the question was closed.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for that... I didn't initially realize there was a separate section for soundtrack credits. Sorry they closed so can't give you credit.

Comment: @Aaron Actually looking at your rep you may have been the one to close, lol. Either way, thanks.